# Breaking down a timed sequence into episodes

Tags: r

I'm trying to break down a vector of event times into episodes. An episode must meet 2 criteria. 1) It consists of 3 or more events and 2) those events have inter-event times of 25 time units or less. My data is organized in a data frame as shown below.

So far, I figured out that I can find the difference between events with diff(EventTime). By creating a logical vector that corresponds to events that the 2nd inter-event criterion, I can use `rle(EpisodeTimeCriterion)` to get a the total number, and length of episodes.

```
    EventTime   TimeDifferenceBetweenNextEvent     EpisodeTimeCriterion
    25          NA                                 NA
    75          50                                 TRUE
    100         25                                 TRUE
    101         1                                  TRUE
    105         4                                  TRUE
    157         52                                 FALSE
    158         1                                  TRUE
    160         2                                  TRUE
    167         7                                  TRUE
    169         2                                  TRUE
    170         1                                  TRUE
    175         5                                  TRUE
    178         3                                  TRUE
    278         100                                FALSE
    302         24                                 TRUE
    308         6                                  TRUE
    320         12                                 TRUE
    322         459                                FALSE
```

However, I would like to know the timing of the episodes and 'rle()' doesn’t let me do that.

Ideally I would like to generate a data frame that looks like this:

```
    Episode      EventsPerEpisode   EpisodeStartTime   EpisodeEndTime
    1            4                  75                 105
    2            7                  158                178
    3            3                  302                322
```

I know that this is probably a simple problem but being new to R, the only solution I can envision is some series of loops. Is there a way of doing this without loops? Or is there package that lends itself to this sort of analysis?

Thanks!

Edited for clarity. Added a desired outcome data fame and expanded the example data to make it clearer.

Comment: That's not quite what rle is used for.

Comment: So, you are looking to group 'episodes' as ones occurring within 25 time units as specified in EventTime column?

Comment: No, not exactly if I understand you correctly. An episode consists of events that are separated by 25 time units or less (as in the EventTime column). In other words an episode can exceed 25 time units if this criterion is met.

Comment: What are you looking for? By "the timing of the episodes" do you mean the total length, start and end times, or something else? If you edit with what your desired result looks like, you'll probably get an answer.

Comment: @alistaire Thanks for you're advice. I've edited the question to include the desired result and expanded on the data included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the pieces you need. You really need to make a variable that gives each episode a number/name so you can group by it. `rle(...)$length` gives you run lengths, so just use `rep` to repeat a number that number of times:

```
runs <- rle(df$EpisodeTimeCriterion)$lengths   # You don't need this extra variable, but it makes the code more readable
df$Episode <- rep(1:length(runs), runs)
```

so `df` looks like

```
> head(df)
  EventTime TimeDifferenceBetweenNextEvent EpisodeTimeCriterion Episode
1        25                             NA                   NA       1
2        75                             50                 TRUE       2
3       100                             25                 TRUE       2
4       101                              1                 TRUE       2
5       105                              4                 TRUE       2
6       157                             52                FALSE       3
```

Now use `dplyr` to summarize the data:

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>% filter(EpisodeTimeCriterion) %>% group_by(Episode) %>% 
  summarise(EventsPerEpisode = n(), 
            EpisodeStartTime = min(EventTime), 
            EpisodeEndTime = max(EventTime))
```

which returns

```
> df2
Source: local data frame [3 x 4]

  Episode EventsPerEpisode EpisodeStartTime EpisodeEndTime
    (int)            (int)            (dbl)          (dbl)
1       2                4               75            105
2       4                7              158            178
3       6                3              302            320
```

If you want your episode numbers to be integers starting with one, you can clean up with

```
df2$Episode <- 1:nrow(df2)
```

#### Data

If someone wants to play with the data, the results of `dput(df)` before running the above code:

```
df <- structure(list(EventTime = c(25, 75, 100, 101, 105, 157, 158, 
    160, 167, 169, 170, 175, 178, 278, 302, 308, 320, 322), TimeDifferenceBetweenNextEvent = c(NA, 
    50, 25, 1, 4, 52, 1, 2, 7, 2, 1, 5, 3, 100, 24, 6, 12, 459), 
    EpisodeTimeCriterion = c(NA, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, FALSE)), .Names = c("EventTime", "TimeDifferenceBetweenNextEvent", 
    "EpisodeTimeCriterion"), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach I came up with using a combination of `cut2` from `Hmisc` package and cumsum to label episodes into numbers:

```
library(Hmisc)
library(dplyr)
df$episodeCut <- cut2(df$TimeDifferenceBetweenNextEvent, c(26))
df$episode <- cumsum((df$episodeCut == '[ 1,26)' & lag(df$episodeCut) != '[ 1,26)') | df$episodeCut != '[ 1,26)')
```

Output is as follows:

```
  EventTime TimeDifferenceBetweenNextEvent EpisodeTimeCriterion episodeCut episode
1        25                             50                FALSE    [26,52]       1
2        75                             25                 TRUE    [ 1,26)       2
3       100                              1                 TRUE    [ 1,26)       2
4       101                              4                 TRUE    [ 1,26)       2
5       105                             52                 TRUE    [26,52]       3
6       157                             52                FALSE    [26,52]       4
```

As you can see, it tags rows 2, 3, 4 as belonging to a single episode.

Is this what you are looking for? Not sure from your description. So, my answer may be wrong.

Comment: Thanks! That does take me a step closer