# Creating Episodes for Groups based on Date Sequence

Tags: r, date, sequence

I'm trying to group my data by a variable (ID) and then create episodes based on dates.   This post helped me to create the output I'm looking for, but I can't figure out how to create the episodes for a grouping variable (ID).  [Breaking down a timed sequence into episodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35167359/breaking-down-a-timed-sequence-into-episodes)

The suggestion in the linked post above works well, but only for one ID.

```
runs <-rle(df$EpisodeTimeCriterian)$lengths
df$Episode <- rep(1:length(runs),runs)
```

I'm most comfortable using dplyr to group data, but when I tried to group_by and then create the Episode variable, I received an error.

```
df %>%
   group_by(ID)%>%
   mutate(Episode = rep(1:length(runs),runs))

Error: Column `Episode` must be length 42 (the group size) or one, not 66
```

## Update:

Thanks to Ben's suggestion below, I was able to group them by individual ID, but now I'm realizing I have done the time between dates wrong.  I want a new episode to start if 30+ days have passed since the previous date.  I thought I accomplished this by calculating the difftime between, but it isn't working.

I would like the Expected episode:

```
# A tibble: 24 x 5
   ID    Date       days_until_next EpisodeTimeCriterian expected
   <chr> <date>               <dbl> <lgl>                   <dbl>
 1 456   2013-10-07               7 TRUE                        1
 2 456   2013-10-14             119 FALSE                       1
 3 456   2014-02-10             220 FALSE                       2
 4 456   2014-09-18               4 TRUE                        3
 5 456   2014-09-22               3 TRUE                        3
 6 456   2014-09-25               7 TRUE                        3
 7 456   2014-10-02               6 TRUE                        3
 8 456   2014-10-08               8 TRUE                        3
 9 456   2014-10-16              97 FALSE                       3
10 456   2015-01-21              15 TRUE                        4
11 456   2015-02-05              21 TRUE                        4
12 456   2015-02-26              41 FALSE                       4
13 456   2015-04-08              57 FALSE                       5
14 456   2015-06-04              12 TRUE                        6
15 456   2015-06-16               2 TRUE                        6
16 456   2015-06-18              49 FALSE                       6
17 456   2015-08-06              14 TRUE                        7
18 456   2015-08-20              42 FALSE                       7
19 456   2015-10-01              12 TRUE                        8
20 456   2015-10-13              16 TRUE                        8
21 456   2015-10-29              12 TRUE                        8
22 456   2015-11-10              65 FALSE                       8
23 456   2016-01-14               1 TRUE                        9
24 456   2016-01-15            -830 TRUE                        9
```

#### Current Attempt

```
df <- original %>%
    group_by(ID)%>%  arrange(ID,Date)%>%
    mutate(days_until_next = abs(difftime(Date,lead(Date,1),units="days")))%>%
  mutate(EpisodeTimeCriterian= days_until_next <=30 | is.na(days_until_next))

runs <-rle(df$EpisodeTimeCriterian)$lengths
df$Episode <- rep(1:length(runs),runs)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(
    Episode2 = {
      r <- rle(EpisodeTimeCriterian)
      r$values <- cumsum(rep(1, length(r$values)))
      inverse.rle(r)
    }
  ) %>%
  print(n=66)
```

### Data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("123", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123", 
"123", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123", 
"123", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123", 
"123", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123", 
"123", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123", 
"456", "456", "456", "456", "456", "456", "456", "456", "456", 
"456", "456", "456", "456", "456", "456", "456", "456", "456", 
"456", "456", "456", "456", "456", "456"), Date = structure(c(15986, 
15993, 16000, 16007, 16014, 16021, 16028, 16035, 16042, 16056, 
16066, 16077, 16084, 16091, 16093, 16094, 16098, 16105, 16106, 
16133, 18130, 18137, 18139, 18144, 18151, 18164, 18176, 18190, 
18197, 18204, 18211, 18218, 18225, 18232, 18239, 18246, 18253, 
18254, 18267, 18274, 18281, 18288, 15985, 15992, 16111, 16331, 
16335, 16338, 16345, 16351, 16359, 16456, 16471, 16492, 16533, 
16590, 16602, 16604, 16653, 16667, 16709, 16721, 16737, 16749, 
16814, 16815), class = "Date"), days_until_next = c(7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 14, 10, 11, 7, 7, 2, 1, 4, 7, 1, 27, 1997, 7, 
2, 5, 7, 13, 12, 14, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 1, 13, 7, 7, 
7, -2302, 7, 119, 220, 4, 3, 7, 6, 8, 97, 15, 21, 41, 57, 12, 
2, 49, 14, 42, 12, 16, 12, 65, 1, -830), EpisodeTimeCriterian = c(TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-66L))
```

### Data (updated, only ID=456)

```
df %>%
structure(list(ID = c("456", "456", "456", "456", "456", "456", 
"456", "456", "456", "456", "456", "456", "456", "456", "456", 
"456", "456", "456", "456", "456", "456", "456", "456", "456"
), Date = structure(c(15985, 15992, 16111, 16331, 16335, 16338, 
16345, 16351, 16359, 16456, 16471, 16492, 16533, 16590, 16602, 
16604, 16653, 16667, 16709, 16721, 16737, 16749, 16814, 16815
), class = "Date"), days_until_next = c(7, 119, 220, 4, 3, 7, 
6, 8, 97, 15, 21, 41, 57, 12, 2, 49, 14, 42, 12, 16, 12, 65, 
1, -830), EpisodeTimeCriterian = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE
), expected = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 
6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here might be one approach. I added the newer output with `group_by` as `Episode2` next to `Episode` created from the initial example. Hope this is helpful.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(
    Episode2 = {
      r <- rle(EpisodeTimeCriterian)
      r$values <- cumsum(rep(1, length(r$values)))
      inverse.rle(r)
    }
  ) %>%
  print(n=66)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 66 x 6
# Groups:   ID [2]
   ID    Date       days_until_next EpisodeTimeCriterian Episode Episode2
   <chr> <date>               <dbl> <lgl>                  <int>    <dbl>
 1 123   2013-10-08               7 TRUE                       1        1
 2 123   2013-10-15               7 TRUE                       1        1
 3 123   2013-10-22               7 TRUE                       1        1
 4 123   2013-10-29               7 TRUE                       1        1
 5 123   2013-11-05               7 TRUE                       1        1
 6 123   2013-11-12               7 TRUE                       1        1
 7 123   2013-11-19               7 TRUE                       1        1
 8 123   2013-11-26               7 TRUE                       1        1
 9 123   2013-12-03              14 TRUE                       1        1
10 123   2013-12-17              10 TRUE                       1        1
11 123   2013-12-27              11 TRUE                       1        1
12 123   2014-01-07               7 TRUE                       1        1
13 123   2014-01-14               7 TRUE                       1        1
14 123   2014-01-21               2 TRUE                       1        1
15 123   2014-01-23               1 TRUE                       1        1
16 123   2014-01-24               4 TRUE                       1        1
17 123   2014-01-28               7 TRUE                       1        1
18 123   2014-02-04               1 TRUE                       1        1
19 123   2014-02-05              27 TRUE                       1        1
20 123   2014-03-04            1997 FALSE                      2        2
21 123   2019-08-22               7 TRUE                       3        3
22 123   2019-08-29               2 TRUE                       3        3
23 123   2019-08-31               5 TRUE                       3        3
24 123   2019-09-05               7 TRUE                       3        3
25 123   2019-09-12              13 TRUE                       3        3
26 123   2019-09-25              12 TRUE                       3        3
27 123   2019-10-07              14 TRUE                       3        3
28 123   2019-10-21               7 TRUE                       3        3
29 123   2019-10-28               7 TRUE                       3        3
30 123   2019-11-04               7 TRUE                       3        3
31 123   2019-11-11               7 TRUE                       3        3
32 123   2019-11-18               7 TRUE                       3        3
33 123   2019-11-25               7 TRUE                       3        3
34 123   2019-12-02               7 TRUE                       3        3
35 123   2019-12-09               7 TRUE                       3        3
36 123   2019-12-16               7 TRUE                       3        3
37 123   2019-12-23               1 TRUE                       3        3
38 123   2019-12-24              13 TRUE                       3        3
39 123   2020-01-06               7 TRUE                       3        3
40 123   2020-01-13               7 TRUE                       3        3
41 123   2020-01-20               7 TRUE                       3        3
42 123   2020-01-27           -2302 TRUE                       3        3
43 456   2013-10-07               7 TRUE                       3        1
44 456   2013-10-14             119 FALSE                      4        2
45 456   2014-02-10             220 FALSE                      4        2
46 456   2014-09-18               4 TRUE                       5        3
47 456   2014-09-22               3 TRUE                       5        3
48 456   2014-09-25               7 TRUE                       5        3
49 456   2014-10-02               6 TRUE                       5        3
50 456   2014-10-08               8 TRUE                       5        3
51 456   2014-10-16              97 FALSE                      6        4
52 456   2015-01-21              15 TRUE                       7        5
53 456   2015-02-05              21 TRUE                       7        5
54 456   2015-02-26              41 FALSE                      8        6
55 456   2015-04-08              57 FALSE                      8        6
56 456   2015-06-04              12 TRUE                       9        7
57 456   2015-06-16               2 TRUE                       9        7
58 456   2015-06-18              49 FALSE                     10        8
59 456   2015-08-06              14 TRUE                      11        9
60 456   2015-08-20              42 FALSE                     12       10
61 456   2015-10-01              12 TRUE                      13       11
62 456   2015-10-13              16 TRUE                      13       11
63 456   2015-10-29              12 TRUE                      13       11
64 456   2015-11-10              65 FALSE                     14       12
65 456   2016-01-14               1 TRUE                      15       13
66 456   2016-01-15            -830 TRUE                      15       13
```

**Edit (3/2/20)**:

I think if the rule is *a date difference of >= 30 days begins a new episode* could be easier than the previous approach. See if this works for you:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(difftime = Date - lag(Date, default = first(Date)),
         expected2 = cumsum(difftime >= 30) + 1) %>%
  print(n=24)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 24 x 7
# Groups:   ID [1]
   ID    Date       days_until_next EpisodeTimeCrit~ expected difftime expected2
   <chr> <date>               <dbl> <lgl>               <dbl> <time>       <dbl>
 1 456   2013-10-07               7 TRUE                    1   0 days         1
 2 456   2013-10-14             119 FALSE                   1   7 days         1
 3 456   2014-02-10             220 FALSE                   2 119 days         2
 4 456   2014-09-18               4 TRUE                    3 220 days         3
 5 456   2014-09-22               3 TRUE                    3   4 days         3
 6 456   2014-09-25               7 TRUE                    3   3 days         3
 7 456   2014-10-02               6 TRUE                    3   7 days         3
 8 456   2014-10-08               8 TRUE                    3   6 days         3
 9 456   2014-10-16              97 FALSE                   3   8 days         3
10 456   2015-01-21              15 TRUE                    4  97 days         4
11 456   2015-02-05              21 TRUE                    4  15 days         4
12 456   2015-02-26              41 FALSE                   4  21 days         4
13 456   2015-04-08              57 FALSE                   5  41 days         5
14 456   2015-06-04              12 TRUE                    6  57 days         6
15 456   2015-06-16               2 TRUE                    6  12 days         6
16 456   2015-06-18              49 FALSE                   6   2 days         6
17 456   2015-08-06              14 TRUE                    7  49 days         7
18 456   2015-08-20              42 FALSE                   7  14 days         7
19 456   2015-10-01              12 TRUE                    8  42 days         8
20 456   2015-10-13              16 TRUE                    8  12 days         8
21 456   2015-10-29              12 TRUE                    8  16 days         8
22 456   2015-11-10              65 FALSE                   8  12 days         8
23 456   2016-01-14               1 TRUE                    9  65 days         9
24 456   2016-01-15            -830 TRUE                    9   1 days         9
```

Comment: That's wonderful!  Thank you!

It has identified something else I did wrong, however.  The last date in an episode will get pushed to the next episode... For example, rows 43 and 44 should be Episode 1, and then Episode 2 should start with row 45.  Any suggestions for fixing that one?

Comment: Could you describe the rule/logic again? Is that because rows 44 and 45 have 2 `FALSE` in a row? Would this also apply to rows 54 and 55? Would you be willing to update your question with the "expected" `episode` column values? I can try to revise the answer to match your desired outcome.

Comment: I updated with the expected values, and new data to play with.  Perhaps the time between wasn't the best way to figure out the start/end points, but I couldn't think of another way.

Comment: @akano see edited answer. If the rule is based on >= 30 day difference, then the approach could be simplified. See if this meets your needs.

Comment: I was definitely over-complicating.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For those that may need something similar for larger datasets, I've written a high-performance function to do exactly this, utilising data.table and collapse.

```r
# remotes::install_github("NicChr/timeplyr") # Tidy-Time based functions
library(dplyr)
library(timeplyr)

res <- df %>%
  time_episodes(ID, time = Date, window = 30,
                .add = TRUE)
#> Assuming a time granularity of 1 day(s)
res
#> # A tibble: 24 x 9
#>    ID    Date       days_un~1 Episo~2 expec~3 time_~4 episo~5 episo~6 episode_~7
#>  * <chr> <date>         <dbl> <lgl>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <int>   <int> <date>    
#>  1 456   2013-10-07         7 TRUE          1      NA       1       1 2013-10-07
#>  2 456   2013-10-14       119 FALSE         1       7       1       0 2013-10-07
#>  3 456   2014-02-10       220 FALSE         2     119       2       2 2014-02-10
#>  4 456   2014-09-18         4 TRUE          3     220       3       3 2014-09-18
#>  5 456   2014-09-22         3 TRUE          3       4       3       0 2014-09-18
#>  6 456   2014-09-25         7 TRUE          3       3       3       0 2014-09-18
#>  7 456   2014-10-02         6 TRUE          3       7       3       0 2014-09-18
#>  8 456   2014-10-08         8 TRUE          3       6       3       0 2014-09-18
#>  9 456   2014-10-16        97 FALSE         3       8       3       0 2014-09-18
#> 10 456   2015-01-21        15 TRUE          4      97       4       4 2015-01-21
#> # ... with 14 more rows, and abbreviated variable names 1: days_until_next,
#> #   2: EpisodeTimeCriterian, 3: expected, 4: time_elapsed, 5: episode_id,
#> #   6: episode_id_group, 7: episode_start
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

It also works with groups so you can supply groups (e.g. gender) through the usual `group_by()` semantics.